# twitter bootstrap - centered navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a little bit confused. I like to center the menu items of a normal bootstrap navigation bar.
But I can't find the right class i have to edit. should I use `text-align`, or `margin: 0 auto;` to realize something like this?

Currently I tried to add this CSS-arguments in `.navbar`, `.navbar-inner` and `.nav`.
Nothing works.

If there are some bootstrap dev's, please help me!

Do you know if there is a Forum for bootstrap stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, it looks like the selector you should be modifying is `.navbar .nav`

Modifying that selector, you can proceed to implement your margin approach:

```
.navbar .nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: ...px;     /* width of .navbar .nav */
    float: none;
}
```

or, similar to what Nick mentioned:

```
.navbar .nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: ...px; /* half of width of .navbar .nav */
}
```

I didn't delve into this too much, but it looks like `.navbar .nav` is getting a width associated to it (for me, it was 1170px). Because of its width, `margin: 0 auto` has no impact... would be nice to come up with a solution that didn't require hard-coding a width (or half-width margin-left).

Answer (score 1):

Assign fixed height, and then asign `margin: 0 auto;` to element that you have to center, but remember center `div` should not be `floated` or `position: absolute;` and it have fixed width
**for example**

```
 <div class="parent">
      <div class="inn"> ... </div>
    </div>
```

To center `.inn` should have fixed width, and not `floated or position: absolute`,
i.e.

```
.inn{
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: when I like to center a vertical ul-list. Will I have to write <ul class="inn"> to center my nove or the <navbar-inner>container of bootstrap? Or will I have to use my own <iv class"inn"><ul> structure?

Comment: Class names are just from exmple, not complsury to use :), Just understand the concept of how to center the block element

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the following:

```
#div-id-inside-navbar{
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -100px /* This should be half the width of your centered content */
}
```

I have centered logos on my bootstrap site and this is what I had to do. I haven't looked into the exact reason why, but I don't believe `text-align: center;` was working all that well. This is similar to the way people often vertically center stuff with CSS.